# How do I display image in the middle?

Tags: android, android-layout

I got width and height of the screen by following code

```
WindowManager wm = ((WindowManager)context.getSystemService(context.WINDOW_SERVICE));
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

m_nDisplayWidth     = display.getWidth();
m_nDisplayHeight    = display.getHeight();
```

Shouldn't this code place my image in the middle of the screen?

```
canvas.drawBitmap(m_circle1, (m_nDisplayWidth/2),(m_nDisplayHeight/2), null);
```

My image is located near the right corner.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: did u tried with 'imgview.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below code for placing image in center.

```
canvas.drawBitmap(m_circle1, (m_nDisplayWidth/2 - imageWidth/2),(m_nDisplayHeight/2 - imageHeight/2), null);
```

where `imageWidth` is width of your image and `imageHeight` is height of your image.

Comment: what is minSDKversion in your manifest file? It should not be 3 and it should be above 3 to have correct values from display.getWidth() and display.getHeight().

Comment: It was set to 3, and I set it to 4 and fixed a lot. But it still seem a bit lower from the center. http://i.stack.imgur.com/wV1Gq.png

Comment: Make sure you are using correct values of imageHeight and not mistakenly using imageWidth or some other value inplace of it. Can you paste your code here also?

Comment: image_w = m_circle1.getWidth();
image_h = m_circle1.getHeight();

Comment: canvas.drawBitmap(m_circle1, (m_nDisplayWidth/2-image_w/2),(m_nDisplayHeight/2-image_h/2), null);

Comment: When you are using this code WindowManager wm = ((WindowManager)context.getSystemService(context.WINDOW_SERVICE));
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
m_nDisplayWidth     = display.getWidth();
m_nDisplayHeight    = display.getHeight();
you are taking whole screen width and height and in your case title bar and notification bar is also showing, but we have to take in account only canvas drawing area. If you want to use current code make your activity full screen by using android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" in your manifest for your activity.

Comment: Or use this code canvas.drawBitmap(m_circle1, (surfaceviewWidth/2 - imageWidth/2),(surfaceviewHeight/2 - imageHeight/2), null);. In this case you are using your SurfaceView Width and Height by using method getWidth() and getHeight() of SurfaceView class.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
canvas.drawBitmap(m_circle1, (m_nDisplayWidth - m_circle1.getWidth()) / 2,(m_nDisplayHeight - m_circle1Height()) / 2, null);
```

Comment: After run your code, it still seem a bit lower from the center. i.stack.imgur.com/wV1Gq.png